# line art or freestyle border pass 2d fill object what can i do to stop this

Tags: freestyle, lineart

***strong text***[image]

line art or freestyle border pass 2d fill object what can i do to stop this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i tried to combine 2d and 3d animation but when i tried to do so the line art of 3d object goes over my 2d greace pencil object what can i do to stop this